# Creating a text by adding variable data

Tags: java

I have IOS experience on programming, now I am trying to re-do all my apps on Java. (Android Studio). For a little while I was re-searching a way to do that:

```
FlightTimeHours.text = NSString(format:"%@:0%.f",Hh , FM) as String
```

So I have 2 Questions:

1) How to format the text as above?

2) I do not want to send the result to a TextView but to a String. (*String FlightTimeHours;*)

Below it is where I am:

```
String AFCR = (String) (FlightTimeHours);
AFCR.setText("0%%:0%.1f", Hh, FM);
```

or

```
String AFCR.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"0%%:0%.1f", Hh, FM));
```

I am lost please help!

Thank you

Comment: Please check here : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%@` corresponds to `%s` and you need to set a precision for float format, e.g. `%.6f`.

Try this:

```java
// note the Java naming convention:
// variable names should start in lower case.
String flightTimeHours = String.format("%s0:%.6f", Hh, FM);

// a pedantic version, with constant locale and parameter ordering
String flightTimeHours = String.format(Locale.US, "%1$s0:%2$.6f", Hh, FM);
```

Comment: Java variables are usually named with lowerCamelCase, not AllCamelCase, so I'd propose changing FlightTimeHours to flightTimeHours. It doesn't change the logic, but as Christian is learning Java, it would be good to give him some good habits.

Comment: For the LowerCase, I was doing the right way at the beginning, but with the time, I slowly change this Upper and Lower Case to fit the way I organize my self through the different aspect of the coding as; var, let and Core data. Help  me to keep track what is what, withOut have to go back every time to figure it out how I should write it.

Comment: @Christian ok. If it works, please consider accepting the answer